# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'log'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I cloned  https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN.git and tried to run demo.ipynb

With these two lines,

```
# Create model object in inference mode.
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=config)

# Load weights trained on MS-COCO
model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True)
```

I got the following error

```
~\Desktop\Neuer Ordner\Mask RCNN\Mask_RCNN-master\mrcnn\model.py in log2_graph(x)
339 def log2_graph(x):
340     """Implementation of Log2. TF doesn't have a native implementation."""
--> 341     return tf.log(x) / tf.log(2.0)
342 
343 

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'log'
```

I followed the solutions as per  https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1797
like down versioning tensorflow to 1.13.1 and using tf.math.log(). But nothing helped.

I also tried running some log functions. But It returned results! I don't know where the problem is.

```
>>> z=tf.log(x)
>>> with tf.Session() as sess:  print(z.eval())
...
[      -inf -0.6931472  0.         1.609438 ]
```

Comment: Stucked on exactly the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

After
`pip3 install -r drive/mrcnn/Mask_RCNN-master/requirements.txt`,
you can use `!pip3 install 'tensorflow==1.14.0'`
and then restart runtime.

Answer (score -1):

you can use tensorflow version 1.14.0 
by install this command

```
!pip install 'tensorflow==1.14.0'
```

and then restart runtime

make sure use tensor-flow version is 1.14 by run this command

```
import tensorflow

print(tensorflow.__version__)
```